# Weird blurriness affecting Stack Overflow - potentially from snippet

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

If you are running the latest [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) on Windows, take a look at question *[Blurry CSS tooltips on Chrome on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710595/blurry-css-tooltips-on-chrome-on-windows)*.

Run the snippet, (remark on the blurriness of the font), then go to answer, and try and upload an image. Is the text in the box blurry? Like the screenshot below? Note how even the text of the background image is somewhat blurred.

[image]

Then if I close the popup, click on a link for another question and do the same, it's fine again. Like below:

[image]

The screenshots don't do it justice. Can anyone else reproduce this?

If you do see this, my thoughts are that it must be the CSS from the snippet doing this, so potentially a bug?

Comment: Reproduced, Chrome 51.0.2704.79 on Windows 7. Also confirmed this only happens _after_ running the snippet on the page. I opened the image dialog first, it was fine, then ran the snippet and opened it again to get the blurry version.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 52.0.2743.24 beta (64-bit) on Xubuntu.  Similar repro steps to @Kendra.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Chrome... Firefox 47beta doesn't seem to reproduce it on Windows 10

Comment: Edge 25.10586.0.0/EdgeHTML 13.10586 doesn't reproduce it either

Comment: It's the CSS property declaration that does it:  `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`

Comment: Reprod as well win7 chrome

Comment: The text isn't blurred but straight-out chopped.

Comment: Can someone do some DOM inspection on the image uploader in this state and see if snippet styles are applied? Adam Lear and I are 99% sure it's a Chrome bug, investigating.

Comment: @Haney They aren't. Gonna call this one a Chrome issue.

Comment: [I see no difference](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/50957690.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue in Chrome only. Looking at the image uploader once it's been blurred, I don't see any of the snippet's CSS styles applied to any of the elements, which is how it should be... So who knows ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

May be worth it to file a bug report [with Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) directly.

In the meantime, I'm picking [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) out of sheer desperation.

Comment: Also, the Snippets iframes are `sandbox="allow-modals allow-scripts"` which means *no* parent DOM access (guaranteed to never be same origin even!) and only alert-type modals and scripts like JS are enabled in the iframe. So this is very clearly Chrome's rendering engine breaking and not obeying the laws of sandboxed iframes.

Comment: Would [status-deferred] be better, seeing is it's kinda buggy but we don't know what do to with it?

Comment: Jokes aside, wouldn't [status-bydesign] imply that this behavior is intended on your part (which seems simply untrue, given that you seem unsure of why this happens) -- as opposed to potentially by-design on Chrome's part?

Comment: @Undo Not really, since this isn't our bug. There's no "deferred" fix. [status-notourfault] would be appropriate, but that ain't an option. I picked bydesign because *as far as our code goes* everything is functioning as intended.

Comment: @doldt See my comment to Undo above. I can't speak for what is or isn't intended by Chrome. Our status tags only apply to our code and our code as far as we can tell behaves both correctly and as designed.

Comment: Alternatively, [support] tag would also be an option, but let me count the ways I don't care about the perfectly precise tagging... :)